# Core Data NSBatchDeleteRequest appears to leave objects in context

Tags: ios, core-data

I have seen many questions regarding batch deletion in Core Data, but none seem to address my issue.

I am creating an iOS 9 / Swift app using Core Data. At WWDC this year, I attended the Core Data session and saw that I could use `NSBatchDeleteRequest` to delete large numbers of objects directly from the persistent store. This works for me for some objects but not others, and I think it has something to do with my relationships.

I have an object graph consisting of `Subject` and `Course`, where there is a one-to-many relationship. Subjects may own as many courses as they wish.

There is a 'courses' relationship on `Subject` with a delete rule of `Cascade`, as I want all courses associated with a `subject` to be deleted when a `subject` is deleted.

The inverse is 'subject' on `Course`, with a delete rule of `Nullify`. Here, I am a bit confused as to Apple's description of `Nullify`:

> Remove the relationship between the objects but do not delete either object.
>   This only makes sense if the department relationship for an employee is optional, or if you ensure that you set a new department for each of the employees before the next save operation.

That makes it pretty clear, but why would the relationships be deleted but not either object? If I delete a `Course`, I would like the `Course` to be deleted and the relationship from the `subject` to the `course` to be deleted so that a fault to the deleted `Course` will not appear in the `NSSet` on `Subject`'s `courses` Set.

I want to provide a way for all objects in an entity to be deleted. When I try this by individually fetching and deleting each `course`, `courses` are properly deleted and removed from the `NSSet` of `courses` on a `Subject`.

Since I have no idea how many `courses` will be present and I want to ensure high performance in every situation, I figured I would use batch deletion to delete all `courses`. The problem is that while utilizing `NSBatchDeleteRequest` to delete all `Subjects` works fine, deleting all `courses` along the way (because of the `Cascade` rule), trying to delete all `Courses` using this method appears to leave all objects in place.

I used `NSBatchDeleteRequest` to delete all `Courses`, but then when I query the `MOC` to see what `Subjects` and `Courses` still exist, both `Courses` are still returned and the `Subject` owning them still has references to them.

In contrast, when I fetch and delete each `Course` individually, my subsequent fetch properly displays an empty array for all `Courses` and the 'courses' relationship on the `Subject` appears to have been properly modified.

Yes, I am saving the context after executing the request. I suppose the context may not be notified of what the store does, but then again deleting all `subjects` worked great. What is going on here?

Comment: Batch deletes disregard delete rules. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915874/can-i-use-nsbatchdeleterequest-on-entities-with-relationships-that-have-delete-r/46073965#46073965

Answer (score 37, accepted):

At [the WWDC 2015 session which describes `NSBatchDeleteRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-220/) it was explained that *"Changes are not reflected in the context*". So what you're seeing is normal. Batch updates work directly on the persistent store file instead of going through the managed object context, so the context doesn't know about them. When you delete the objects by fetching and then deleting, you're working through the context, so it knows about the changes you're making (in fact it's performing those changes for you).

If you use `NSBatchDeleteResultTypeObjectIDs`, you can merge the results of the batch delete back into your context using `mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:intoContexts:` to update your contexts. You could probably also use `reset`, if you don't have any other managed objects loaded from the context.

Comment: Thanks! I used reset and it worked. Before seeing your answer, I did see that Courses were missing from the SQLite database and the app reflected this upon relaunch.

Comment: I would like to switch to the mergeChanges method for safety. I have a copy of the batch deletion result which I have set to come back as `NSBatchDeleteResultTypeObjectID`. What do I pass for `changeNotificationData: [NSObject: AnyObject]` on `mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave`?

Comment: Okay instead of using `NSBatchDeleteResultTypeObjectID`, I registered for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and called `mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave` from the block.

Comment: @MatthewS Does that work for you? According to the documentation and the session video (WWDC 2015) that shouldn't work. A batch delete request bypasses the managed object context, which means that no notifications are sent that reflect the changes made by the batch delete request.

Comment: @BartJacobs Yes, that works for me. The changes appear to be reflected in the context using this notification-observing method. It may be because I am calling `executeRequest` directly on my context instance.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up adding the following to take care of the context after the batch delete.

```
[self.managedObjectContext refreshAllObjects];
```

Comment: this doesn't do it