# FetchedResults won't trigger and SwiftUI update but the context saves it successfully

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to update an attribute in my Core Data through an NSManagedObject. As soon as I update it, I save the context and it gets saved successfully.

**Problem**

After the context saves it, the UI (SwiftUI) won't update it with the new value. If I add a completely new Children into Core Data (insert) the UI gets updated.

What I tried:

1. [Asperi approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58777603/558801) - I can print out the correct new value in .onReceive but the UI doesn't update
2. Using self.objectWillChange.send() before context.save() - didn't work either
3. Changed the Int16 to String, because I was speculating that somehow Int16 is not observable? Didn't work either

Is this a SwiftUI bug?
As-is State

```
//only updating the data 
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext        
let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest<Card>(entityName: "Card") //filter distributorID; should return only one Card
fetchReq.resultType = .managedObjectResultType
fetchReq.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", params["id"]!) //I get an array with cards
var cards :[Card] = []
cards = try context.fetch(fetchReq)

//some other functions
cards[0].counter = "3" //
//...
self.objectWillChange.send() //doesn't do anything?
try context.save()
//sucessfully, no error. Data is there if I restart the app and "force" a reload of the UI
```

```
//Core Data "Card"
extension Card :Identifiable{

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Card> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Card>(entityName: "Card")
    }

    //...
    @NSManaged public var id: String
    //....

}
```

```
//Main SwiftUI - data is correctly displayed on the card
@FetchRequest(entity: Card.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [],
                  predicate: nil)

var cards: FetchedResults<Card>
List {
     ForEach(cards){  card in
     CardView(value: Int(card.counter)!, maximum: Int(card.maxValue)!, 
     headline: card.desc, mstatement: card.id)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If first code block is a part of ObservableObject, then it does not look that third block, view one, depends on it, and if there is no changes in dependencies, view is not updated.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60230873/12299030) approach.

But if there are dependencies, which are just not provided then change order of save and publisher as

```
try context.save()
self.objectWillChange.send()
```

Comment: I have setup an EnvironmentObject which is stuck on the main view. In there I am changing the data and saving the context. But context ist just         let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

Comment: Got it working in this order - now the UI updates: 1. save the context 2. reset the context 3. self.objectWillChange.send()