# How can I refresh the SwiftUI coreData @FetchRequest result?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I am using coreData and loading my model using the following:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateAdded_", ascending: false)], animation: .default)
private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
```

The problem is when I update the one-many relation of an item and saveContext on main thread, the view is not refreshed.  I'm assuming the changes to the relations are not observed.

```
item.addToItemRelations(itemRelation)
try? context.save()
```

I don't think I will be able to make this work consistently using toggle's and other hacks.  Just wondering if there is anyway to force the @FetchRequest to fetch the entire result again?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60230873/12299030?

Comment: Yes.  It helped tremendously.  And as usual @Asperi you have saved me a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 4):

If you want so show the child records then you'll need another `@FetchRequest` to monitor the changes of the entity of the related records using the inverse relation and parent object in the predicate. You need a child view that you supply parent item and another child view within that you init with a FetchRequest. The reason for the wrapper View is explained [in this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71085942/259521).

If you just want to show a computation of the child records, e.g. a count or sum, then you can first implement that using a derived attribute in the model editor. Then after the save call `context.refresh(item, mergeChanges:true)` and it'll reload in the object and since the derived attribute is different the `@FetchRequest` should detect it and cause body to be invoked.

Comment: sorry, did you mean context.refresh(item, mergeChanges: true)? because the NSManagedObject item doesn't have a refresh property as far as I can see.  For context.refresh(item.. that didn't work for me.

Comment: oh sorry you're right that won't work. I've updated my answer with another possible solution