# NSBatchInsertRequest fetch objects after its completed

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using a batch insert request like this:

```
let insertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: EntryObject.entity(),     managedObjectHandler: { object in
    guard index < total else { return true }
    
    if let entryObject = object as? EntryObject {
        let entry = entries[index]
        entryObject.setValues(entry: entry, shouldAttemptFetchExistingTags: true)
    }
    
    index += 1
    return false
})
try context.execute(insertRequest)
```

Each `EntryObject` needs to be related to several other entities. However, `NSBatchInsertRequest` doesn't allow creating relationships. Each object is saved directly to the store without loading it into a context.

So my plan is to fetch each of these objects afterwards and apply the necessary relationships.

I'm using a batch insert request because `EntryObject` can contain several movies that are expensive as crap to create, and I'm continually getting super hard to trace crashes.

However when I go back to fetch these objects.. they don't exist.

I tried storing the objectIDs in a temporary array. That threw the same error.
Then I tried manually merging the changes into the context I performed the batch insert on, in addition to the viewContext.

```
insertRequest.resultType = NSBatchInsertRequestResultType.objectIDs
                let result = try context.execute(insertRequest) as! NSBatchInsertResult

                if let objectIDs = result.result as? [NSManagedObjectID], !objectIDs.isEmpty {
                    let save = [NSInsertedObjectsKey: objectIDs]
                    NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: save, into: [PersistenceController.viewContext, context])
                }
```

And when that didn't work, I watch the 2018 best practices for CoreData and got this going..

```
    try context.performAndWait {
        let request = NSPersistentHistoryChangeRequest ()
        request.resultType = .transactionsAndChanges
        let result = try context.execute (request) as! NSPersistentHistoryResult
        let transactions = result.result as! Array<NSPersistentHistoryTransaction>
        for transaction in transactions {
            context.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: transaction.objectIDNotification())
        }
    }
    try context.save()
```

It's supposed to merge all the changes to the store into the main context.

However when I go back to fetch these objects, on either context.. they don't exist. Not until I kill the app and start over.

I've been trying to figure out how to completely reinit a store.. but have had no success.

How do I fetch these objects right after I create them using an `NSBatchInsertRequest`?

Comment: Work done with Core Data BatchRequests aren’t automatically reflected in the ManagedObjectContext. You need to perform that step yourself. The answer at the end of this question might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74019146/batchdelete-works-but-must-restart-app-for-changes-to-show